# js2-mode: Highlighting and syntax checks only update when the buffer or mode is refreshed

Tags: syntax-highlighting, js2-mode

As I'm typing into my buffer in `js2-mode`, the syntax is not being updated and all my new code is plain white. Additionally, existing text keeps its original color. For example, when I uncomment some commented code, the color is still darkened as if it were still a comment.

I can refresh my buffer via `C-x C-v RET` or refresh the mode via `M-x js2-mode RET`, which updates the highlighting, but this is annoying. Any suggestions?

Additionally, syntax errors that are shown in the mini buffer do not go away unless I refresh the buffer or mode as well.

After enabling `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, here is the output of my `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Debug on Error enabled globally
Saving file /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js...
Wrote /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js
Saving file /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js...
Wrote /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js
Saving file /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js...
Wrote /home/lucas/class/nodeschool/how-to-npm/web-sockets.js
```

Any suggestions about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Please attempt to reproduce fontification failure with `debug-on-error` enabled (`M-x toggle-debug-on-error`). Attach backtrace to your message if you get one.

Comment: Check the *Messages* buffer, it may contain messages about errors during jit-lock.

Comment: @Stefan I am led to believe that `js2-mode` does not use jit-lock. I can't find the post I read, but it's floating out there somewhere.

Comment: I updated my questions. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Lucas Enable `debug-on-error`, then evaluate `(js2-reparse t)` in the buffer. If you see a backtrace, post an issue.

Comment: `js2-reparse` itself seems to do the trick, though it shouldn't need to be as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think my questions has enough information to diagnose the problem, but in case someone runs across the same issue, here is how I resolved it:

I had `(js2-minor-mode)` in my hook, although I am using the major mode `js2-mode`. When I toggle `js2-minor-mode` followed by a buffer reload, the parsing error resolves whenever `js2-minor-mode` is disabled. So the solution is to disable `js2-minor-mode`, or remove it from my hook. I'm not sure why a `js2-minor-mode` even exists?

This is a little confusing because there are lots of packages/modes involved with running a Javascript IDE, but I only have a basic understanding of Emacs. If someone can post a more thorough explanation of what's going on, I would gladly accept their answer.

Here is the output of my major and minor modes after the correction, from running `C-h m`:

```
Enabled minor modes: Ac-Js2 Auto-Complete Auto-Composition
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Column-Number
Desktop-Save Electric-Indent Erc-Autojoin Erc-Button Erc-Fill
Erc-Irccontrols Erc-List Erc-Match Erc-Menu Erc-Move-To-Prompt
Erc-Netsplit Erc-Networks Erc-Noncommands Erc-Pcomplete Erc-Readonly
Erc-Ring Erc-Stamp Erc-Track Evil Evil-Local File-Name-Shadow
Font-Lock Global-Auto-Complete Global-Font-Lock Global-Hl-Line
Global-Undo-Tree Global-Visual-Line Line-Number Linum Menu-Bar
Mouse-Wheel Show-Paren Size-Indication Subword Tooltip Transient-Mark
Undo-Tree Yas Yas-Global

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Javascript-IDE mode defined in `js2-mode.el':
Major mode for editing JavaScript code.

In addition to any hooks its parent mode `prog-mode' might have run,
this mode runs the hook `js2-mode-hook', as the final step
during initialization.
```

Comment: `js2-minor-mode` exists to be used with `js-mode`.